# c# format a string of characters so letters before number are capital and after are lowercase

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to format a string in c# and i m not sure if i shoudl be using regex or something like that basically if a modelname is md234GH  and Dgh321Hh They need to be MD234gh and DGH321hh.

So capitals numbers lowercase

I tried doing the following:

```
TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false).TextInfo;

foreach (var product in products)
{
    if (product.ModelName != null)
    {
        product.ModelName = product.ModelName.ToLower();
        product.ModelName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(product.ModelName);
    }
}
```

but this only makes the first letter capital.

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToTitleCase` is only mean to make the first letter of each word upper case.  To do what you want, you'll need to split the string up and call `.ToUpper` and `.ToLower` as appropriate, e.g.:

```
Regex modelExpression = new Regex("^([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)$");

// Inside for loop...
Match m = modelExpression.Match(product.ModelName);
if (m.Success)
{
    product.ModelName = m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() 
         + m.Groups[2].Value 
         + m.Groups[3].Value.ToLower();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ToTitleCase` will only make the first letter of each word upper case.

You need to use `ToUpper` to make all letters upper case.

There is nothing built in to do what you want, so you will need to make your own - parsing the string between the numerals and formatting each part.

A regular expression looks like the best bet:

```
^([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)$
```

Usage:

```
var formatted = Regex.Replace(originalString,
                          @"^([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)$",
                          m => m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() +
                          m.Groups[2].Value +
                          m.Groups[3].Value.ToLower());
```

The result for "md234GH" is "MD234gh" and for "Dgh321Hh" it is "DGH321hh".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```
(?i)^([a-z]+)(\d+)([a-z]+)$
```

In a replace, something like:

```
model = Regex.Replace(model, @"(?i)^([a-z]+)(\d+)([a-z]+)$", delegate(Match m)
{
    return m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() + m.Groups[2].Value + m.Groups[3].Value.ToLower();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are a good match for this:

```
\b(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)\b
```

Now all that is needed is to use the regex api in C# and give it a delegate that does the replace. I've used a lambda as the delegate:

```
var result = Regex.Replace("md234GH", @"\b(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)\b", x =>
    x.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() 
    + x.Groups[2].Value 
    + x.Groups[3].Value.ToUpper() 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Match m=Regex.Match("md234GH","(\\w+?)(\\d+)(\\w+)");
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}",m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper(),m.Groups[2].Value,m.Groups[3].Value.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in plain C. This assumes 8-bit ASCII or ANSI character set is used.

```
void convertModelName(char *name)
{
    char    *ptr;
    int     lcase = 0;

    for (ptr=name; *ptr; ptr++) {
        if (*ptr >= '0' && *ptr <= '9') {
            lcase = 1;
        } else {
            if (lcase) {
                *ptr |= 0x20;
            } else {
                *ptr &= 0xdf;
            }
        }
    }
}
```